# JMeter Switch Controller

Tags: jmeter

How I can user variables in switch controller. I need this kind of logic:
ThreadGroup contains: counter (start with 1000 and ends with 1020, referense name = record_id), httpRequest(use record_id as a parameter), switch controller (switch value = ${record_id}) and inside switch controller I have size assertion named 1000. But this size assertion is't working. How I can make switch controller working with diffrent cases like 1000, 1001 etc (record_id(counter)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch controller must contain samplers or controllers named 1000, 1001, etc. An assertion is not switchable so no point naming it 1000, you need to name the sample that the assertion applies to.